# C# Outlook, is there a way to track conversation if topic was changed?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, mailitem

I am developing a VSTO tool using C# and I need to track conversations from customers. Using ConversationID will do most of the job, however if customer change the topic, completely new ConversationID will be generated and the the new messages will be considered as new conversation. Is there a way to link these messages with the original ones?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, the `ConversationID` property is generated based on the subject (normalized subject, i.e. without RE: or FW: prefixes).

A conversation is a group of related messages that have the same `ConversationTopic` property value. For example, users can save original messages and responses in their personal folders. Messages can be tagged with the `ConversationIndex` property so that users can order the messages within the conversation.

If you want to track items you can simply add an ID to the subject string and track such subjects to group messages if required or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Hello Eugene, thanks for your response. I understand your point. The main problem in this tool is that if you receive an email(root mail), most of the times you will need to reply or forward this mail to someone else. And when you receive a response from them, most of the times their reply will have slightly changed subject. This means that new conversation ID and Topic will be generated and my event handler for incoming mails will not be able to link these to the root mail.

Comment: If I set a custom user property to the root email, is there a way to pass this to all its replies and forwards in the future?

Comment: UserProperties are removed when you reply to a message.

Comment: I understand, thanks. So there is absolutely no chance to link messages with changed subject with their root items/parents?

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything else. On the MAPI level you can develop your own store provider where you may implement your own logic for generating conversation-related property values.